# Do I need to worry about griefing PvP?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know the official PvP patch is coming Soon™, but until then do I need to be worried like in *Diablo II* that someone can come into my game and gank my guy?  Is PvP possible under any circumstances at all?

Answer (score 4):

No.  There will be no open world PvP.

All PvP will be team-based and in [arenas](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/4574895).

Comment: Good to know +1.