# Activating Friendly Fire

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm wondering if theres a way to activate Friendly Fire in Diablo 3.

The extra challenge (and chaos) would be quite fun to have.

So is there a way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to worry about griefing PvP?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66214/do-i-need-to-worry-about-griefing-pvp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to activate friendly fire or PVP of any sort. However, according to the [Diablo wiki](http://www.diablowiki.net/Diablo_3_Basics#Battle_Arena), PVP is planned to be added in the future:

> All PvP in Diablo III takes place in the Arena. Unfortunately, this feature will not be included when Diablo III ships, as the developers could not get it ready in time for the launch.

Since PVP is limited to the Arena, there likely won't be any friendly fire in the main game when PVP does launch. Again, from the wiki:

> Unlike in Diablo II, there will not be any non-consensual PvP in Diablo III; there is no more "hostile switch" or any other way to duel or PK in a normal game. PvP will be supported only in special dueling Arena games.